# UISplitViewController For Universal Apps in Swift

Tags: swift, segue, uisplitviewcontroller

Here is my scenario i done for UISplitViewController for Both iPhone and iPad using Swift but i am facing little bit issues on iPad, iPhone work flawless !

[image: MainStoryBoard.swift]
**Prepare for Segue Method**

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {    
    if (segue.identifier == "showDetail"){
        let nav = segue.destination as! UINavigationController
        let vc = nav.viewControllers[0] as! detailViewController

        let selectedIndexPath: IndexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow!
        vc.selectedRecipeArray = [foodRecipeClassArray[selectedIndexPath.row]]
    }
}
```

The iPhone Result is Ok. When I click on `MasterViewController` it goes to `DetailViewController`, but on iPad there is an issue. See below.

[image: When tap on master detail view controller then it not showing resultset in detailViewController]